# Media Library: Remove replace images of selected author

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

Bigger WordPress install here: ~14k posts, 20k images in media library (plus different image sizes - cropped & formats).

Images are used 
- as featured image of multiple posts
- inside content (partly linked to media file) in different sizes (like thumbnail, medium, cropped, full...)
- there is no way to tell uploader by filename / folder.

I have to replace or remove **all media files** from **one author** (over 3k images) but a "replacement" for these would be nice (because a lot of posts would loose featured images and have a lot of broken links inside content.

So how would I do that? How would I "replace" 3k images with a "default image", how would I replace or delete all of these image links in my post content (plus image_300x150.jpg, image_600x200.jpg, ...)

Sorry for my horrible english - but i have NO IDEA what options I have.

Comment: First of all, welcome to WPSE. For a part it could be interesting about the *WHY*, an answer could depend on it.

Comment: hey Charles. Let's say: a former author used a lot of copyrighted images and I just want to get rid of all of them asap without destroying the whole website.